# Getting php to read from a form created through javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms

I'm creating text boxes and a set of radio buttons using Javascript, the idea is I click submit after that and php grabs the fields entries and puts them into a mysql database.

However I'm finding if I create the form elements using javascript php does not see them. If I create them in html though there's no problem. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Show HOW you create them - for example give the elements a name

Comment: The only issue is the way your creating the elements, you must not be creating them to the RFC Minimum standards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you create the input elements within a `<form>` element, or that you use AJAX to submit them.

Comment: Yep taht's the solution, I just realized when I was creating them myself I was placing them in the correct form element. Funny how that solution dawned on me the minute I posted this after it had been driving me crazy for the last half hour :D I'll mark your question as the answer in ten minutes (stackoverflow spam filter is preventing me from doing it right away)